# Is there a theoretical limit on the charging speed of a lithium ion battery?

Tags: batteries

I'm wondering about lithium batteries in electric cars. Could time and technology improvements continue to improve charging speed, to the point where you could "refill" an electric car as fast as you can refill a gas tank? Or is there something potentially impossible to surmount there, like a law of thermodynamics?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about one or more of the lithium battery technologies which are in place today? Or is your question about a theoretical limit on the rate of charging any battery, under any circumstances?

Comment: I'm interested in both, but I specifically asked about lithium ion batteries (any variation), to try to narrow the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if given sufficient time & improved technology we may be able to eventually increase the charging speed electric car batteries, even to the point where it's faster than refilling a gas tank. However, our current technology is far from such vast improvement. There are multiple factors that would need to be considered in order to make such improvements, such as how much of its original energy capacity a battery with increased charging speed loses after, say, 100 charge cycles. For instance, if, after just 100 charge cycles the battery capacity is only 50% of its starting capacity, then it's likely a worse product than currently available batteries.

Additionally, there may be some factors, such as the amount of excess heat generated while charging, which are always a problem and which prevent the product from being available to the general public.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).